# Erro ao executar consulta mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

Estou obtendo o seguinte erro ao executar a consulta

> 1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'protetic_sistema.cad_trabalho.id_trabalho' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

```
SELECT *,ANY_VALUE(cad_trabalho.id_trabalho) as trabalho, DATE_FORMAT(data_saida_trabalho, '%d/%m/%Y') AS data_saida, DATE_FORMAT(cad_estagio.data_estagio, '%d/%m/%Y') AS data_estagio FROM cad_trabalho
JOIN cad_paciente ON cad_trabalho.id_paciente = cad_paciente.id_paciente
JOIN cad_cliente ON cad_paciente.id_cliente = cad_cliente.id_cliente
LEFT JOIN cad_estagio ON cad_trabalho.id_trabalho = cad_estagio.id_trabalho and cad_estagio.id_estagio = (select max(id_estagio) from cad_estagio where id_trabalho = cad_trabalho.id_trabalho)
WHERE cad_trabalho.pronto_trabalho = '0000-00-00'
GROUP BY cad_trabalho.id_paciente
ORDER BY cad_trabalho.data_saida_trabalho ASC
```

e quando adiciono

`mysql_query("SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''))");`

meu sistema fica muito lento.

Comment: É simples, todas as colunas/expressões que estão na cláusula SELECT precisam estar também na GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

Como já foi comentado todas as colunas que estão no seu `SELECT` precisam estar no seu `GROUP BY`. Caso você não queira fazer isso você pode desabilitar o `sql_mode`.

```
mysql > SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

Comment: meu servidor/hospedagem nao me permite fazer essa alteracao :(

Comment: Então a solução é colocar todas as colunas no group by.

Answer (score 0):

Você deve trazer no `SELECT` todas as colunas que estão sendo passadas no `GROUP BY`.

Tente adicionar na seleção(**SELECT**), as colunas que estão sendo agrupadas(**GROUP BY**).

Ou apenas desabilite no seu servidor mysql, a diretiva `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`, que é responsável por restringir esse tipo de consulta:

```sql
SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''))
```

Espero que isto ajude!

Comment: meu servidor/hospedagem nao me permite fazer essa alteracao :(